# Find Percentage of difference between two Videos Using FFMPEG

Tags: java, ffmpeg

I am working with Video comparison using FFmpeg on Java. I have videos name "video1 and Video2". I can find the difference between two video using FFmpeg.

It shows the result Video with difference. But here I want to find how many percent (IE: 20%) Video1 different from Video2. How to achieve this?

Comment: Define "differences".

Comment: I have edited my question. I think it explain my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If just file comparison, lots of tools can do that.

If video content comparison, you need to scale the 2 videos to the same width & height and calculate SSIM of each pair of frames.  SSIM is short for "Structural similarity", which is a float number between 0 and 1, where 1 stands for totally the same and 0 the opposite.

FFMPEG has a [SSIM Filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#ssim) to do what I just said.  It would give you a text file containing SSIM comparison of all frames.  Then your program can parse this file and get what you want.